# IdentityServer4 Role Based Authorization with ASP.NET Core Identity and EF model

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, role-base-authorization

I have a IdentityServer4 project that protects a Web API. I am using ASP.Net CORE identity with local SQL Server. The authorization works fine when using [Authorize] in API controllers. When I use [Authorize(Roles = "QLTester")], however, I always gets 403 forbidden. I have a feeling that I may not have the correct configuration in the identity database. But should I configure the users and roles so they can be picked up by the system correctly?

Here is the cross reference record from the AspNetUserRole table

[image]

and here is the Role defined in AspNetRoles table

[image]

What else do I need besides these? or maybe I am doing it completely wrong.

Comment: Please check the AspNetUsers table, whether the Login user's UserId match the item in the AspNetUserRoles table? And, can you post the related code in the Startup.cs file? Might be the issue is related to the configuration. Besides, you could also check the Claims in the HttpContext, perhaps the Role Claims doesn't add to the HttpContext. If that is the case, try to use [userManager.AddClaimAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addclaimasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method to add the specified claim to the user.

Comment: Thanks Zhi Lv. Yes, the user ID does match between those tables. Regarding the role claims (I guess that's part of my confusion here), I just want to do a simple role based authorization, not claim based. So in that case, I don't need anything from AspNetRoleClaims table, correct? I also added a record in ClientScopes table for "role". Any other tables I may need? Above all, which token (identity or access) will I find the role from?

Comment: Hi @Alexu, "I don't need anything from AspNetRoleClaims table, correct?", Yes, you are right, generally there is no need to add claims into the AspNetRoleClaims table. After configuring the Role Based Authorization, the Asp.net core Identity will add a role claim to the HttpContext.User, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e03B4.png), you could check it in your application. So, in my previous reply, I suggest you check it and add it by yourself. Besides, if above method still not working, I suggest you configure your application to use Policy or Claims based Authorization.